# PAO.Pyomo model sets two variables x and y to be unique

Tags: linear-programming, pyomo, mixed-integer-programming, integer-programming

The background is I am trying to implement a bilevel optimization program using Python-based package for Adversarial Optimization ([PAO](https://pao.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)), which is based on Pyomo. I am new to Pyomo, though I have used many solvers such as Gurobi and Cplex previously. To solve the bilevel optimization program, I need to use the pao.pyomo.MIBS solver. However, I found my Pyomo program can't even solve a naive unequal constraint `z[0] != z[1]` correctly. My code is as follows, which is trying to assign values to `z[0], z[1] \in {0, 1}` that satisfy constraint `z[0] != z[1]` :

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo
from pyomo.environ import *
from pao.pyomo import *

N = 2
M=1024

model = ConcreteModel()
model.z = Var(range(N), domain=Integers)
for i in range(N):
    model.z[i].setlb(0)
    model.z[i].setub(N-1)

model.delta = Var(range(N), range(N), domain=Binary)

model.unique_z = ConstraintList()
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(i+1, N):
        model.unique_z.add(model.z[i] - model.z[j] + M*(1-model.delta[i, j]) >= 1)
        model.unique_z.add(model.z[i] - model.z[j] - M*model.delta[i, j] <= -1)

model.obj = Objective(expr=sum(model.z[i] for i in range(N)), sense=maximize)
model.L = SubModel(fixed=model.z)

with Solver('pao.pyomo.MIBS') as solver:
    results = solver.solve(model)

print("obj =", model.obj.expr(), "z =", [model.z[i].value for i in range(N)])
```

So the basic constraint is like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37075/how-can-not-equals-be-expressed-as-an-inequality-for-a-linear-programming-model), which expresses the not equal constraint `z[0] != z[1]` as a linear constraint with the help of binary variables `delta`. An obvious solution is either `z[0]` or `z[1]` is 1 and the other variable is 0.

However, I have printed the model's output and found the model sets both `z[0]` and `z[1]` to be 0.

```
>>> model.z.pprint()
z : Size=2, Index=z_index
    Key : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
      0 :     0 :     0 :     1 : False : False : Integers
      1 :     0 :     0 :     1 : False : False : Integers

>>> model.delta.pprint()
delta : Size=4, Index=delta_index
    Key    : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
    (0, 0) :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
    (0, 1) :     0 :     0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
    (1, 0) :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
    (1, 1) :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary

>>> model.unique_z.pprint()
unique_z : Size=2, Index=unique_z_index, Active=True
    Key : Lower : Body                                : Upper : Active
      1 :   1.0 : z[0] - z[1] + 1024*(1 - delta[0,1]) :  +Inf :   True
      2 :  -Inf :       z[0] - z[1] - 1024*delta[0,1] :  -1.0 :   True
```

So when `z[0]`, `z[1]`, and `delta(0,1)` are 0, doesn't this violate the constraint `z[0] - z[1] - 1024*delta[0,1] <= -1`? I don't understand why this can be feasible.

I'm a beginner with Pyomo. If there are any misconceptions in the model I've built or in the Pyomo outputs, I would greatly appreciate any clarification or suggestions. Thank you.

---

**Edit**: Thanks to @AirSquid, it seems the problem is with my 'pao.pyomo.MIBS' solver. Could anyone give some suggestions on what's wrong with my current implementation of 'pao.pyomo.MIBS' solver? I have to use this solver for my bilevel optimization program.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect there is something wrong with your solving code and you are looking at an un-solved or erroneous solve of some kind.  I'm not familiar with the code sequence you are using there.  I usually:

- get a solver instance from the `SolverFactory`
- catch the solve result
- inspect the solve result. <-- must do to ensure optimal or result is junk.

Your math is correct.  I tweaked your model a tiny bit and used a different solver, but it's working.  You are double importing.  You should be able either use your first *or* second import line.  I prefer the `pyo` prefix, but either way.  I commented out the `pao` as it isn't used in my example.

Note that in `pyomo`, `pprint` shows the construction w/ variable names, and `display` can be used to fill in (or show) the solved values

#### Code:

```
# import pyomo.environ as pyo
from pyomo.environ import *
# from pao.pyomo import *


N = 6
M=1024

model = ConcreteModel()
model.z = Var(range(N), domain=Integers)
for i in range(N):
    model.z[i].setlb(0)
    model.z[i].setub(N-1)

model.delta = Var(range(N), range(N), domain=Binary)

model.unique_z = ConstraintList()
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(i+1, N):
        model.unique_z.add(model.z[i] - model.z[j] + M*(1-model.delta[i, j]) >= 1)
        model.unique_z.add(model.z[i] - model.z[j] - M*model.delta[i, j] <= -1)

model.obj = Objective(expr=sum(model.z[i] for i in range(N)), sense=maximize)
# model.L = SubModel(fixed=model.z)

solver = SolverFactory('cbc')
results = solver.solve(model)

# DO THIS.  Check for "OPTIMAL"
print(results)

print("obj =", model.obj.expr(), "z =", [model.z[i].value for i in range(N)])

# easy way to inspect the output of a variable (or the whole model)
model.z.display()
# model.display()
```

#### Output:

```
Problem: 
- Name: unknown
  Lower bound: 15.0
  Upper bound: 15.0
  Number of objectives: 1
  Number of constraints: 30
  Number of variables: 21
  Number of binary variables: 15
  Number of integer variables: 21
  Number of nonzeros: 6
  Sense: maximize
Solver: 
- Status: ok
  User time: -1.0
  System time: 0.27
  Wallclock time: 0.46
  Termination condition: optimal
  Termination message: Model was solved to optimality (subject to tolerances), and an optimal solution is available.
  Statistics: 
    Branch and bound: 
      Number of bounded subproblems: 270
      Number of created subproblems: 270
    Black box: 
      Number of iterations: 4106
  Error rc: 0
  Time: 0.47368288040161133
Solution: 
- number of solutions: 0
  number of solutions displayed: 0

obj = 15.0 z = [2.0, 4.0, 0.0, 1.0, 3.0, 5.0]
z : Size=6, Index=z_index
    Key : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
      0 :     0 :   2.0 :     5 : False : False : Integers
      1 :     0 :   4.0 :     5 : False : False : Integers
      2 :     0 :   0.0 :     5 : False : False : Integers
      3 :     0 :   1.0 :     5 : False : False : Integers
      4 :     0 :   3.0 :     5 : False : False : Integers
      5 :     0 :   5.0 :     5 : False : False : Integers
```

Comment: Thanks, I think the problem is with my solver. Not sure what's wrong with my usage of this MIBS solver, but I have to use it for my bilevel optimization task...

Comment: I see, were you worried that `Solver` was imported from `pyomo.environ`? I think there is no `Solver` in `pyomo.environ`. I also changed my code to `import pyomo.environ as pyo` and still have the same output from MIBS solver...

Comment: @Francis.  Disregard the deleted comment.  I'm not sure you have the submodel and "fixing" done correctly, but this is not an area I have experience in.  Have you tried to replicate the examples from the dox with the MIBS solver?  https://pao.readthedocs.io/en/latest/representations/pyomo.html

Comment: Unfortunately, they don't have many examples with MIBS solver, the one https://github.com/or-fusion/pao/blob/master/pao/pyomo/examples/mibs.py you shared with me before I can get the same optimal solution. The issue might be I didn't set the submodel appropriately since I let it be empty, thanks for your suggestions.